# How to create a automatic update component in php?

Tags: php, version-control, curl, software-update

I'm developing a web application in PHP and I need to develop an automatic update component for that software. When I thought about how to develop this, this is what came to my mind:

*logic*

- download latest version as a zip file to the server
- unzip
- upload and overwrite the files already existing and if there are number of versions available:

  - assume user is having 1.2 version and he need to update to the 1.5 newest version
  - system will download all the versions after 1.2 and overwrite files one by one with the files of 1.3, 1.4 and 1.5 versions.

This seems a big overload to the server. I really don't have another idea. I hope you all can hep me out. And I also want to know what kind of PHP technologies I can use for this?

Comment: Have you read this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2439160/how-to-self-update-phpmysql-cms ?

Comment: If it is just about overwriting files why not downloading the latest available version? Of course newest version should be complete, not just difference to the previous one.

Comment: hi thanks you for your replies.  mugur : i have't and i will now.
 dev-null-dweller : that's how i thought too.. until my boss told me something else - that newest is different to the previous :/